# How do I configure Django to look at the correct Sass installation?

Tags: django, sass, libsass

I've taken over a project and I'm having some difficulty getting the server running.

I'm getting the error:

```
'module' object has no attribute 'compile'
```

When I go into a shell:

```
>>> from django_libsass import SassCompiler
>>> import sass
<module 'sass' from '/home/.../venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sass.so'>
>>> print sass.compile(string='a { b { color: blue; } }')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compile'
```

`pip freeze` reports that the following are installed:

```
libsass==0.13.5
django-libsass==0.7
sass==2.3
```

`which sass` shows `/usr/bin/sass` which is version `3.4.21`.

I take it it might be an issue with my settings.   Nothing explicitly sets any paths but I do have this:

```
STATIC_PRECOMPILER_COMPILERS = (
    ('static_precompiler.compilers.libsass.SCSS', {
        "sourcemap_enabled": True,
        "load_paths": ["/path"],
        "precision": 8,
    }),
    ('static_precompiler.compilers.libsass.SASS', {
        "sourcemap_enabled": True,
        "load_paths": ["/path"],
        "precision": 8,
    }),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was this:

```
sass==2.3
```

`libsass` and `django-libsass` provide a `sass` module for you, and installing any other `sass` module with `pip` only serves to obscure `libsass`.